# What does ICA using only one component return?

Tags: scikit-learn, entropy, information-theory, independent-component-analysis

I understand that with multiple components, the result will be coefficients that lead to maximally independent series.

When requesting only one component I'm unclear if it actually does optimization and what that optimization is. Since there is only one component, there is nothing to measure an independence against? My intuition is that it might return the coefficients that result in the maximum entropy series, but I have no idea.

Specifically I'm asking about sklearn's FastICA, but a general answer would be great too.